# can I use preg_match instead of deprecated eregi here and if so how?

Tags: php

current code

```
eregi("(.*)/index.php$", $scriptName, $regs)
```

thinking along lines of

```
preg_match("(.*)/index.php$", $scriptName, $regs)
```

but not sure what the $regs bit is and also what I need to change in the brackets to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match_all("/(.*)\/index.php$/", $scriptName, $regs)
```

Note you can use most characters as regex delimiters in PHP, e.g. `~`.

> but not sure what the $regs bit is and also what i need to change in the brackets to make it work?

`$regs` will be the matches. `preg_match_all()` has this behaviour, with the third argument. It is passed by reference, so you can simply start subscripting `$regs` if there were successful matches. `[0]` will have the entire match, and `[1]` will have the portion proceeding `/index.php` at the end of the string.

As for changes in brackets, I've always called those parenthesis so I will assume that is what you meant (sorry for nitpicking). Are you referring to the arguments inside the function's parenthesis, or the matching group in the regex itself? Either way, just use the code above :)

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.eregi.php

### Warning

This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged